# R create list or matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix

If I repeat this code

```
x<-1:6
n<-40
M<-200
y<-replicate(M,as.numeric(table(sample(x,n,1))))
str(y)
```

sometimes R decide to create a matrix and sometimes it creates a list. Can you explain me the reason for that? How can I be sure that it is a matrix or a list?

If you chose M very small, for example 10, it will almost always create a matrix. If you chose M very large, for example 2000, it will create a list.

Comment: You get a list when there are non-uniform lengths of the result as it can't be simplified.  More replications = higher chance of encountering a result where one or more of the values of `x` wasn't sampled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a list for cases when not all the numbers in `x` are sampled.

You can always return a list by using `simplify = FALSE`.

```
y <- replicate(M, as.numeric(table(sample(x,n,TRUE))), simplify = FALSE)
```

Also, you are using `1` to set `replace` argument. It is better to use logical argument i.e `TRUE`.

---

To return always a matrix, we can do :

```
sapply(y, `[`, x)
```

This will append `NA`'s for values where length is unequal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a way to return always a matrix? If not, how can i get from this structure of list to a matrix?

Comment: Do you want to append `NA`'s for lists with unequal length?

Comment: @Triss - one way would be to make `x` a factor, then table will return zero for values that weren't sampled.

Comment: Yes NA's for example

Comment: I have updated the answer but I liked @H1's suggestion. If you do `x<-factor(1:6)`, it will always return a matrix with equal length and then you don't need the above `sapply` step but it will return 0 instead of `NA` if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

May be it will help
[https://rafalab.github.io/dsbook/r-basics.html#data-types][1]
Vectors in matrix have to be all the same type and length
Vectors in list can contain elements of different classes and length
Try this:

```
x<-1
y<-2:7
z<-matrix(x,y)
z<-list(x,y)
```

In first case you will get matrix 2 rows and 1 column because y vector is longer
In the second case you will get a list with elements of different length.
Also

```
str()
```

function is very useful. But you can find the class of object using

```
class()
```

function.